# Name change in AD is not reflected correctly in MOSS

Tags: sharepoint

I have a user whose display name has been updated and now the MOSS profile database and people search shows up fine but when the user logs in the "Welcome " message in the upper left corner is still the old value and so is the data in "My settings" if you select it from the drop down menu.

How can I get these data to update correctly? (I have tried to remove the profile, add it again and do a profile import but that has not cleared the last errors.)

Comment: The issue solved itself after a while (guess that som caching played tricks on us). Accepted the answer because it was valid and sound advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. First, make sure that the content database is set to **online** (Central Admin -> Web applications -> Content Databases) and not offline. When offline user name changes do not propagate.

Since you said this is MOSS, make sure your SSP user profiles are set to synchronize on a schedule (they are not by default). Set a schedule if not set up.

You can also try to force a user profile synchronization them by running `stsadm -o sync`

Comment: I did a full profile import and the profile in MOSS is fine, its ONLY the username on the front page and the data you access there that fails...

Comment: Tried the forced sync and verified that the database is online - it does not change the appearence for the user

Comment: so the username appears correctly in other parts of the site? (files, items, etc)

Comment: yes as far as I can see... People search, profile etc. is all working fine... :o/